# How to set the frame of GPUImagePicture

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImage framework for editing video, do you know how can I set the size and position (the frame) of a GPUImagePicture when I blend it with my video?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a GPUImageTransformFilter right after the GPUImagePicture instance to change the scale or translation of the image relative to you source video.